# How can I use :only in conjunction with :include in the to_xml in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I'm trying to make use of both :only and :include options in to_xml call in a Rails app. Here's the code:

```
current_user.to_xml(
  :include => :subscription,
  :only => [:email, :username]
)
```

The result of this is somthing like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <username>cristi</username>
  <email>cristi@example.com</email>
  <subscription>
  </subscription>
</user>
```

The problem is that subscription has more fields, which are not included. I assume its because of the `:only` option.

Is there a way to overcome this (show all fields in the subsscription element), without using `:except` as an option in `to_xml` ?

I am using Rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. It works perfectly for me.

```
>> u = User.first
>> puts u.to_xml(:only => %w( id name ))
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <name>Simone Carletti</name>
  <id type="integer">1</id>
</user>

>> puts u.to_xml(:only => %w( id name ), :include => :domains)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <name>Simone Carletti</name>
  <id type="integer">1</id>
  <domains type="array">
    <domain>
      <name>...</name>
      <id type="integer">0</id>
    </domain>
    <domain>
      <name>...</name>
      <id type="integer">0</id>
    </domain>
  </domains>
</user>
```

Make sure the `:subscription` association is correct. If it's a one-to-many association, you need to use the pluralized version `:subscriptions`.

Comment: This outputs from the `:include`d association only those fields that match the `:only` option. I think the OP wants to output `u.email`, `u.username` and all of `u.subscriptions`, regardless of the field names in `subscriptions`.